# When my embed youtube video finished I can't play it again?

Tags: iphone, webview, youtube, titanium, embed

I have a working webview in Titanium with an embeded youtube video. The video plays nice, I can stop it, resume it and so on. But when the video plays to the end and I press "done". The webview goes black with the text: YouTube. Nothing else. I would like there to be the same thumb and playbutton as before I played the video.

My embeded code looks like this:

```
html:'<html><head></head><body style="margin:0"> <embed id="yt" src="'+tubeURL+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="150" height="113"></embed></body></html>',
```

I've googled this problem for days now. I hope someone can help me here.

Cheers

//Martin

EDIT: This solved it. Put &controls=1&rel=0 in the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube players can be embedded in a web page using either an *< iframe>* tag or an *< object>* tag.

By appending parameters to the SWF or IFrame URL, you can customize the playback experience in your application. For example, you can automatically play videos using the autoplay parameter or cause a video to play repeatedly using the loop parameter or in your case hide or show **controls**.

**controls**

Values: 0, 1, or 2. Default is 1. This parameter indicates whether the video player controls will display. For AS3 players, it also defines when the Flash player will load:

- *controls=0* – Player controls do not display in the player. For AS3 players, the Flash player loads immediately.
- *controls=1* – Player controls display in the player. For AS3 players, the Flash player loads immediately.
- *controls=2* – Player controls display in the player. For AS3 players, the Flash player loads afer the user initiates the video playback.

The correct answer for your question would be ***controls=2***.

SOURCE INFO: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls